# Normalization of solution of Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, normalization

I know that the solution to the dirac equation are of the form:
$\psi(x)=u(\vec{p})e^{ip\cdot x}$ and the spinor can be normalized as
$u^\dagger u =E$. 
 I was reading "Lectures on Quantum Field Theory - Ashok Das" I have two questions :-

1. Why does it write $$\psi(x)=\int{d^4p\space a(p)\space \delta(p^2-m^2)\space e^{ip\cdot x}u(p)}$$
   whay do we have this delta function here ?
2. How can we show that,
   $$\int{d^3x \psi^\dagger \psi}=1$$